# Switch (or replace) value of specific characters

Tags: php, string, replace, switch-statement

I want to write a PHP code that will change the value of specific characters.

For example I have string $text...

```
$text = "ababcdcd";
```

How do I switch their values? Value of a = b, b = a, c = d and d = c. Output should be like...

```
$text = "babadcdc";
```

I already tried using str_replace() but it only changes a single character. Please help me out, thanks.

Comment: [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) does exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtr` is made for this.

```
$text = "ababcdcd";
$tr = array('a' => 'b', 'b' => 'a', 'c' => 'd', 'd' => 'c');
$text = strtr($text, $tr);

echo $text; //Will output babadcdc
```

Comment: It's much terser with the native syntax `strtr($text, "abcd", "badc")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$text = str_replace(array('a','b','c','d'),array('b','a','d','c'), $text);
```

Comment: your suggestion will not work as it will replace the replacement on the subsequent iterations. It will end up outputting `aaaacccc`.

Comment: @hcoat: You are right. It is for replace the world in the string.Check the answer given below

Answer (score 0):

Try This One to get your answer as you want.(If you want to replace a particular word use the code given before)

```
<?php
$i=0;
$text = "ababcdcd";
$text2=$text;
$text = str_replace(array('a','c'),array('b','d'), $text);
$text2=str_replace(array('b','d'),array('a','c'), $text2);
$text3='';

for($i=0;$i<strlen($text);$i++)
{
if($i%2==0)
{
$text3.=substr($text, $i, 1); 
}
else
{
$text3.=substr($text2, $i, 1);
}
}
echo "<br>".$text3;
?>
```